# how to add php code in .tpl file in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Does anyone know how to add php code in `.tpl` file in prestashop..i tried a lot but couldn't find any solutions..I want to add a mail function in my `.tpl` file

This is the function

```
<?php
    $name=$_REQUEST["name"];
    $email=$_REQUEST["email"];
    $matter=$_REQUEST["matter"];
    $subject=$name."has shared a weblink";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $contactMsg = '
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Tell A Friend</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>E-mail: '.$email.' </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Comment: '.$matter.' </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    $headers .= "from:abcd" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: Info <info@abcd.in";
    $headers .= "reply-to:".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc:".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";
    if(mail($email, $subject, $contactMsg, $headers))
    {
    $_REQUEST = array();
    $error.="Mail Sent Successfully"; 
    }
    else
    {
    $error.="Error Mail Sent Fail!"; 
   // 
    }
 ?>
```

i tried writing the code inside `{php}` `{/php}` block..but couldn't help
And how to see the `error log` in `prestashop`

Comment: why would you add FUNCTION in TEMPLATE file

Comment: I have a page where i want to send an email to my friends..hence i want to write a mail function on that page

Comment: add it in your bussiness logic

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the controller file, eg. if you want to add the form in a cms page, you have to edit this */controller/CMSController.php*

edit this

```
public function displayContent()
{
  parent::displayContent();
  self::$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms.tpl');
}
```

with this

```
public function displayContent()
{
 IF  ($_POST['submit_form']==1){
   // here submit action mail() for example
 }
  parent::displayContent();
  self::$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms.tpl');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to add `php` functions classes etc in your module controller,

`{php}` is depreciated for a reason as it allow poor practices. Smarty recommends putting the included script into the PHP logic `(controllers,classes,functions)`

Comment: I tried that..but it does not look good..i created a `sendmail.php` file and in the form i gave the `sendmail.php` as action name..then the function run successfully but redirect to `sendmail.php` file..that does not look good..i want to stay on that page

Comment: @KingshukDeb Deb in the current page controller add a new method for this mail and you can call it when you need it without redirecting to other page..

Comment: how can i call that method??..i need it in product `listing page`..so i think `FrontController` is the controller..i create a public function and call it in onclick method but failed..tried to create an object of `FrontController` but failed..what to do??

Comment: @Kingshuk Deb call it like this  `$send_email = (int)Tools::getValue('send_email');
  if ($send_email && Validate::isUnsignedId($send_email))
  $this->Mail();`  where mail is your public function and call it like this `?id_category=3&controller=category&send_email=1` ...it will invoke `Mail()` method...

Comment: check this first http://www.presta.iudyog.com/index.php?id_category=4&controller=category

Comment: On hoovering every item a small tab appears which has a `tell a friend` button. in my `product_list` page i have a form which has an onclick method..when you click on this it sends an email to my friend..now how can i write your code in my .tpl file??...is it possible??

Comment: @Kingshuk Deb you need to write code inside controller its not for tpl file..and if you don't want to refresh the page you can use with ajax else you can do as i mentioned above..

Answer (score 0):

The use of the {php}{/php} tags in .tpl files is turned off in somme versions of Prestashop

I had the same problem using Prestashop 1.5.4.1
To turn it on make changes in the file config/smarty.config.inc.php :

find these lines (line 27 to line33)

```
...
define('_PS_SMARTY_DIR_', _PS_TOOL_DIR_.'smarty/');

require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');

global $smarty;
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setCompileDir(_PS_CACHE_DIR_.'smarty/compile');
...
```

change it to

```
...
define('_PS_SMARTY_DIR_', _PS_TOOL_DIR_.'smarty/');

require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');

global $smarty;
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
$smarty->setCompileDir(_PS_CACHE_DIR_.'smarty/compile');
...
```

...shortly, use SmartyBC.class.php instead of Smarty.class.php

(warning: using {php}{/php} tags in template files is deprecated in Prestashop!)

Comment: ...and to display php-errors in the browser (no to see an error log) you can add a ligne whith this code: 
 ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); to config/config.inc.php , for example after ligne 36 ( where you can see ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0); )